# where can I suggest for new css rule?

Tags: css, css-selectors

There is no parent selector even with css3 but I would like to suggest in css4 we could select parent selector as this

As for child

> E > F  Matches any F element that is a child of an element E.

So far for parent

> E < F  Matches any E element that is a parent of an element F.

As for immediately precedent sibling

> E + F  Matches any F element immediately preceded by a sibling element E.

So far for immediately decedent sibling

> E - F  Matches any F element immediately decedent by a sibling element E.

As for precedent sibling

> E ~ F  Matches any F element preceded by a sibling element E.

So far for decedent sibling

> E ^ F  Matches any F element decedent by a sibling element E.

Hope this would be very useful to all.

Comment: I don't think that is going to happen.  I believe that using child to ancestor relationships is expensive and comes with a number of issues.  But you never know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: There is a spec to specify the subject of a CSS rule, which can be used as a parent selector: [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject). It is currently not implemented, but you are not the first with that idea ;-)

Comment: I'll be watching this and that other question to see if it gets implemented... but think about what you want.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good question for SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where can I suggest for new css rule?

Suggestions for changes to CSS are best addressed to the *www-style@w3.org* mailing list.

See [How To Help](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work#contribute) from the CSS Working Group.

Comment: Keep in mind you'll probably get mercilessly shot down - or at least whisked away to the existing Selectors 4 draft - for suggesting anything like in the given question. Those topics are just about as dead a horse in the mailing list as they are here.

Comment: Indeed. See the second paragraph of the How To Help section.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want `background-color: green;` to bubble up from a box on the side of your page to every parent, including `<body>` and then `<html>`? It would involve lots of wildcards, and redefining parent element styles later on in the stylesheet to make sure things worked right.

We would lose hair twice as fast, I think...

Comment: I think you're confusing ancestor selectors with the `inherit` keyword...

Comment: Maybe. But if you want a style to apply to all parents of `x`, wouldn't you have to make sure subsequent rules don't overwrite them?

Comment: The same can already be done with descendant selectors, so that's not going to be a new issue. Borders don't inherit unless you specify it, so it won't be difficult to override.